# Bootable Windows 10 USB doesn't boot up in Linux

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb, bootable-media

I want to install Windows over Linux. I followed these instructions (https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux) to create a bootable Windows USB. I got the Windows ISO from here (https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO).

But, it will not boot up Windows for me. I went into the BIOS and changed it to boot from USB but that doesn't work, it still boots into Ubuntu.

What else can I try? Is there something I need to do to Ubuntu to solve this? Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use exFAT? As new Windows 10 ISO (.wim install file) is over 4GB and will not fit on FAT32 partition which has a 4GB limit.

Answer (score 0):

Like oldfred said, try reformatting it using exFAT (if not already). Try re-downloading the ISO. If there’s a screen which tells you to “press any key to boot from USB” or something like that, do as it says and press any key (or the key specified if told). Try following a different guide instead. Try using a CD/DVD instead. If none of that works, then borrow a friend’s computer and do it. If it’s a Windows machine, plug in the USB/disc, download the ISO, right-click on it and select “Burn” or something along the lines of that. Please let me know if this solved your question, and at which stage.